# Unpermited params rails 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, strong-parameters

Rails 5.1.1 Ruby 2.4.1

When a new organization is created, The contact information should save to the contact table however that is not the case. I am still relatively new to rails and have looked through other posts with strong params with no luck. I think I have included all the essential pieces to get this working if not let me know and thank you!

**Console output from logger.info in the create action**

```
13:55:03 rails.1   |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:55:03 rails.1   |   Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
13:55:03 rails.1   | <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LIdSKBh7x9Dqs1A6gKb0Gn7EecArG6aflOeC4OARShLwfySH+HQ5joN3FUCe6qmJBGn2K/QRize67qhrxczK+w==", "organization"=><ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Apple", "label"=>"apl", "proxy_hostname"=>"www.apple.com"} permitted: false>, "contact_attributes"=>{"name"=>"555-555-5555"}, "commit"=>"Create Organization", "controller"=>"organizations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
13:55:03 rails.1   | <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Apple", "label"=>"apl", "proxy_hostname"=>"www.apple.com"} permitted: true>
13:55:03 rails.1   |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
13:55:03 rails.1   |   Organization Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `organizations` WHERE `organizations`.`label` = BINARY 'apl' LIMIT 1
13:55:03 rails.1   |   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `organizations` (`name`, `label`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `proxy_hostname`) VALUES ('Apple', 'apl', '2017-06-20 17:55:03', '2017-06-20 17:55:03', 'www.apple.com')
13:55:03 rails.1   |    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
13:55:03 rails.1   | method=POST path=/organizations format=html controller=OrganizationsController action=create status=302 duration=10.23 view=0.00 db=2.12 location=http://localhost:5000/organizations/apl
13:55:03 rails.1   |   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:55:03 rails.1   |   Organization Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` WHERE `organizations`.`label` = 'apl' LIMIT 1
13:55:03 rails.1   |    (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'analyst') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
13:55:03 rails.1   |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `organization_users` ON `users`.`id` = `organization_users`.`user_id` WHERE `organization_users`.`organization_id` = 25
13:55:03 rails.1   |   Sensor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `sensors`.* FROM `sensors` WHERE `sensors`.`organization_id` = '25'
13:55:03 rails.1   |   CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'analyst') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
13:55:03 rails.1   |   Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))
13:55:03 rails.1   |   CACHE Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `users_roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `users_roles`.`user_id` = 1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 1]]
```

**Models**

```
 class Organization < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :contact, optional: true

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
 end

 class Contact < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :organization
 end
```

**Controller**

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_organization, only: [:show, :edit, :update, 
  :destroy]

   after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
   after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index

  def index
    @organizations = policy_scope(Organization)
  end

  def show
    authorize @organization
  end

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new(contact: Contact.new)
    authorize @organization, :create?
  end

  def edit
    authorize @organization, :update?
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
    authorize @organization

    logger.info(params.inspect)
    logger.info(organization_params.inspect)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @organization.save
        format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization 
        was 
        successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: 
        @organization }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: 
        :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    authorize @organization
    respond_to do |format|
      if @organization.update(organization_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization 
        was 
        successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: 
        @organization }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: 
        :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize @organization
    @organization.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to organizations_url, notice: 
      'Organization 
      was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_organization
    @organization = Organization.find_by_label(params[:id])
  end


  def organization_params
    params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :label, 
    :proxy_hostname, 
    :contact_id, contact_attributes: [:name, :email, :phone])
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
= form_for @organization do |f|
  - if @organization.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
    h2 = "#{pluralize(@organization.errors.count, "error")} prohibited 
    this organization from being saved:"
    ul
    - @organization.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
      li = message
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :name, for: :organization_name
    = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :label, for: :organization_label
    = f.text_field :label, class: 'form-control'
  .field.form-group
    = f.label :proxy_hostname, for: :organization_proxy_hostname
    = f.text_field :proxy_hostname, class: 'form-control'

    = fields_for :contact_attributes do |ff|
      .field.form-group
        = ff.label :Contact_Name, for: :contact_name
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        = ff.label :Email, for: :contact_email
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        = ff.label :Contact_Phone, for: :contact_phone
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        .actions = f.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary'
```

Comment: And what's the error, exactly?

Comment: Reformat the parameters snippet to multiple lines. It's unreadable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev according to the logger.info, it permits the name, label and proxy but not the contact_attributes. Or at least thats how I understood that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an `f.` before your fields for

```
 = f.fields_for :contact_attributes do |ff|
      .field.form-group
        = ff.label :Contact_Name, for: :contact_name
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        = ff.label :Email, for: :contact_email
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        = ff.label :Contact_Phone, for: :contact_phone
        = ff.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
        .actions = f.submit class: 'btn btn-outline-primary'
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

your contact_attributes is not nested inside of organization, but in your organization_params you are expecting contact_attributes to be nested. Fix your view, so contact_attributes is nested within organization.

Make the below changes in the view to the contract_attributes

```
  f.fields_for :contract do |ff|
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the shape of your params, you'll see that `organization` and `contact_attributes` are siblings, not parent-nested. This has something to do with your `fields_for`. Off the top of my head, you have to do either this:

```
= fields_for 'organization[contact_attributes]' do |ff|
```

or some form of this:

```
= fields_for organization.contact do |ff|
```

Although in this case, you obviously have to make sure it's not nil.

Or check @Ramon's answer, I think he nailed it.